# Float box to the right and let it overlap elements below static elements

Tags: css, css-float

I want to add a box to a HTML page and style it in a quite uncommon way. I fail to find the right CSS rules or the right search terms. This is how everything should look like:

```
this head might    ,----------------------.
be quite long and  | this box has dynamic |
should wrap to     | height and width and |
the next line      | sticks to right side |
                   |                      |
===================| it will probably be  |===
=== this area    ==| longer than the      |===
=== has full     ==| headline and shall   |===
=== width and    ==| overlap things below |===
=== is below the ==`----------------------'===
=== the box      =============================
==============================================
```

The box displays some statistical data and shall have dynamic dimensions (no fixed height/width). This is how I'd style it:

```
#box {
    float: right;
    z-index: 100;
    width:  auto; /* default, inserted for clarification */
    height: auto;
}
```

The element below the headline is a teaser image with full page width. Because it's only an image and the box is half-transparent it's no problem that the box overlaps the image. I expect the image area to styled like this:

```
#teaser {
    background-image: url('...');
    width: 100%;
 /* clear: both; /* is probably not useful, is it? */
}
```

I can only think of these methods which have major drawbacks:

1. give the box `position: absolute`. I have to used fixed width to make the headline wrap left of the box, otherwise the headline text would run under the box.
2. let the box `float:right` but this way the teaser image will begin only after the box is finished.

Can you think of any solution?

Comment: What kind of box has dynamic width AND height? I would use a div and define the width, as you say, letting the height be dynamic. Use absolute or relative positioning, probably absolute.

Comment: The statistical data is displayed in a table. As there are limited columns and rows I know the rough dimensions but I don't want to set fixed height/width for the table/box.

Answer (score 0):

without giving it too much thought, you could let it float and apply clear[left|right] - whichever suits your needs. Depending the surrounding rules, you may need to set clear also to the image, preferably with a value of [none]. That should let the image flow and the box float without either one getting in the way of the other.

Comment: You might have got my description wrong: I actually need the box to intersect the teaser image while having higher z-index, thus overlapping it. The teaser image *should* get in the way of the box. Maybe "below" is a bit ambiguous here: i want them at same level in vertical direction but below each other in depth. Is it clearer now?

Comment: Not sure, but am tempted to add, afraid not. You want the header to break lines, bounce off the box? That would require both to be on the same stack level. The image _should_ get in the way? By means of the box floating on top of it? Adding a height to #teaser might help. The result gives something like this: [link](http://www.peter-heinrich-claus.eu.org/temp/teaser/)

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your `#teaser` element is clearing the float, or the element above it has a clearfix applied to it (which would contain the floated element inside of that element). By default, floated elements behave exactly as you describe, so something else must be interfering. See this [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FXS7z/1/) for a simple example of the default behavior.